# Crash in AppDelegate on clicking button in NSTableRowView

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, storyboard, nstableview

I am using storyboards for OSX development. I am using NSTableView and different NSTableRowViews are used for rows of this table view. here is the logic-

```
    func getRowView(#forIndex:Int) -> NSTableRowView?{
    if forIndex == lastSelectedRow{
        var storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
        var accountController = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("account") as! CMMAccountViewController
        accountController.accountData = listOfAccounts[forIndex]
        var rowView = accountController.view as! CMMAccountView
        return rowView
    }
    else{
        var rowView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("accountSeetingsRow", owner: self) as! CMMAccountRowView
        rowView.titleLable.stringValue = listOfAccounts[forIndex].nickname!
        rowView.captionLable.stringValue = listOfAccounts[forIndex].accountDisplayName!
        return rowView
    }
}
```

**Problem**: I have a button in view, whose viewcontroller is instantiated at line -

```
  var accountController = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("account") as! CMMAccountViewController
```

And I have CTRl dragged a action from that button in CMMAccountViewController, but whenever I click that button app crashes with EXE_BAD_ACCESS.
Why this is happening? how I am supposed to used that button in NSTableRowView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. Issue was that accountController is local variable and it was getting deallocated once the view is used. I had to keep this reference alive to avoid deallocation of this reference.